# Table tr background gradient on hover using CSS

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

**My requirement:**

On `tr` hover, `tr`will have the linear gradient background, *not only a flat background color*.

Sample `td` in `tr`:

```
A  |  B  |  C  |  B  |  A
```

Where `A darker --> C lighter`

**JSFIDDLE:**

https://jsfiddle.net/g7o84j43/

***Code I've tried:***

*HTML:*

```
<table border="1px" width="100%" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px">
<tr style="text-align:center">
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>A</td>
</tr>
<tr style="text-align:center">
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>A</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

*CSS:*

```
tr:hover
{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: No, I meant the along the row not one td only.

Comment: Your code is working properly to me in Firefox.

Comment: Yup..that's good..but how about in google chrome?So many users use google chrome.

Comment: Not a duplicate @divy3993... I need the whole `tr` to be color in gradient style..

Comment: So..how to solve this? Using jquery?

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/g7o84j43/3/) is a different solution using no extra elements (or) positioning etc. It sets the gradient to the table's background  which is shown on hover. When not hovered, the `tr` background is set to white. I am not sure how helpful this approach would be for you. If it helps, I will add as answer.

Comment: Ok..good solution...you may add as answer.

Comment: Closevoters, this question is by no means a duplicate of the one that is linked in the 4 CVs so far. That solution works **only for solid colors** whereas this is about a gradient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe not the best solution, but maybe good enough for you, and it's working in Chrome too. [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/g7o84j43/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="table-wrapper">
    <table>
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* To hide the overflow */
.table-wrapper{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

tr{
    position: relative;
}

/* Making the background with :before pseudo-element */

tr:before
{
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    z-index: -1;
}

tr:hover:before
{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
```

Comment: That's was close...Can you make it center?

Comment: Center how, can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm glad to help you :)

Answer (score 8):

The simplest and most straight-forward solution to setting a gradient background for `tr` on `hover` is to add `background-attachment: fixed` also to it.

```css
tr:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1), rgba(255, 0, 0, 0), rgba(255, 0, 0, 1));
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<!-- prefix library included only to avoid vendor prefixes -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<table border="1px" width="100%" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px">
  <tr style="text-align:center">
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="text-align:center">
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

Here is a different approach for adding a gradient background to the row (`tr`) while hovering over it. In this approach, we add the gradient as a background to the `table` element itself and then override it for the unhovered state to a solid color (white). When the `tr` is hovered, the background of the `tr` is set to `transparent` and so the `table` background shows through revealing the gradient.

```css
table {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0), rgba(255, 0, 0, 1));
}
tr {
  background: white;
}
tr:hover {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<!-- prefix library included only to avoid vendor prefixes -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<table border="1px" width="100%" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px">
  <tr style="text-align:center">
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="text-align:center">
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

If the lighter color needs to be at the center then the gradient can be modified like in the below snippet:

```css
table {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1), rgba(255, 0, 0, 0), rgba(255, 0, 0, 1));
}
tr {
  background: white;
}
tr:hover {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<!-- prefix library included only to avoid vendor prefixes -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<table border="1px" width="100%" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px">
  <tr style="text-align:center">
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="text-align:center">
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Imran: There seems to be a much more simpler way to add gradient background to `tr` on hover. All that is needed is to add `background-attachment: fixed` to it. Check the first snippet in the answer when you get time :)

Comment: First sample will only work when width on table is set to 100% ... still, upvoted :)