# CSS3 linear-gradient that spans over table row

Tags: css

I'm trying to use `linear-gradient` to make a progress bar out of a table row. I'm applying the style to the row but it acts as if set to each of the cells in the row instead. How would I do this right?

**Example:**

```
<table>
    <tr style="background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF0000 35%, #FFF 35%)">
      <td>Column1</td>
      <td>Column2</td>
      <td>Column3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/b4y2nue9/

Comment: You gonna use this for email?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33490489/table-tr-background-gradient-on-hover-using-css/33492701#33492701 (look at `background-attachment:fixed`)

Comment: @Harry Funny, I used `background-attachment:fixed` first, but it didn't work unless the table's width is set to 100% ... I now see it does if gradient is put on the table ... I'm considering an update of my answer to make it possible to have a different gradient on each row

Answer (score 2):

Revised answer based on [@Harry's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42325512/css3-linear-gradient-that-spans-over-table-row/42326489#comment71808582_42325512) the question being [a possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33490489/table-tr-background-gradient-on-hover-using-css/33492701#33492701)

As @Harry gave a [good answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33490489/table-tr-background-gradient-on-hover-using-css/33492701#33492701), my answer will be an extension to that, where I solely focus on how to set a different gradient on each table row, on a table which is not full viewport width.

The key to make it work, is to set the table width using viewport units, with that, one can set the same width to the absolute positioned pseudo element on the first `td`, which will work properly when `position: relative` is set on the `td`, which doesn't work when set on a [`tr` (See spec.)](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position)

Here is a version using external CSS

```css
table {
  width: 50vw;
}
td {
  position: relative;
}
tr:nth-child(1) td:first-child::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  width: 50vw; bottom: 0;  
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF0000 35%, #FFF 35%);
  z-index: -1;
}
tr:nth-child(2) td:first-child::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  width: 50vw; bottom: 0;  
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #00FF00 35%, #FFF 35%);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>Column1</td>
      <td>Column2</td>
      <td>Column3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column1</td>
      <td>Column2</td>
      <td>Column3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

---

Here is a version using a `div`, if one need it using inline CSS

```html
<table style="width: 50vw">
    <tr>
      <td style="position: relative">
        <div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 50vw; bottom: 0; background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF0000 35%, #FFF 35%); z-index: -1;"></div>
      
        Column1</td>
      <td>Column2</td>
      <td>Column3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="position: relative">
        <div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 50vw; bottom: 0; background: linear-gradient(to right, #00FF00 35%, #FFF 35%); z-index: -1;"></div>
      
        Column1</td>
      <td>Column2</td>
      <td>Column3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: block` on your `tr`and it'll do what you're looking for

#### CSS

```
tr {
  display: block;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF0000 35%, #FFF 35%)
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1z4e4gdz/